# Nvidia (331.38) ignores underscan setting after boot or loging back in

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, nvidia-settings

Anytime I log in to my desktop I can mouse to the right and bottom borders and the screen pans an extra inch or two in those directions. Usually, that part of the desktop isn't mapped and it's just dead space (either blue or black). When I open Nvidia-settings and go to the "X Server Display Configuration" page it is as it should be. Underscan is set at "36". But, I have to change underscan (up one or down one), apply, then change it back to 36 for it to display properly without any panning to dead space. Anyone know how to correct this?

Comment: I am not familiar with your specific drivers, but have you looked at xorg configurations? Xorg is where you keep persistent changes for displays.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've modified xorg.conf in every way imaginable. I've modified the xinit.rc file with the load nvidia config script. I've actually tried so many suggestions that I won't be able to remember them all until I hear them again. Like I said - when I open Nvidia-settings it's showing the proper configuration. But, for some reason I still get off-screen real estate every time I boot until I manually adjust the underscan back and forth to it's current setting of 36. Is something in my display (x,compiz?) starting before my Nvidia Settings have a chance to load?

Comment: What happens when you "Apply" a new setting with Nvidia? The screen goes black for a second and when it's reappears the settings have taken place and you have a countdown in a confirmation dialogue to keep the changes or they reset back to the current default. But what all gets restarted during that process and how do I do I repeat that process via script to run after the desktop initially loads upon start up? That's the only workaround I can come up with. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to compensate the underscan with this command:

```
nvidia-settings -a CurrentMetaMode="DFP-1: 1280x720 { ViewPortIn=1280x720,ViewPortOut=1230x672-25-24 }"
```

Note that this command is for 720p resolution and 25 is the amount of pixels that the dead area goes horizontally and 24 is the amount of pixels that it goes vertically. Substitute those values with desired ones.

If that worked you can make this fix permanent by saving these configurations onto your xorg file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Look for 'Section "Device"', if your xorg doesn't have such section or it is empty, create this section:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier    "Default Device"  
    Option        "NoLogo" "True"
EndSection
```

Under this section add one option so it will be like this:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier    "Default Device"  
    Option        "NoLogo" "True"
    Option        "metamodes" "DFP-1: 1280x720 { ViewPortIn=1280x720,ViewPortOut=1230x672-25-24 }"
EndSection
```

Save it, restart your computer and now it should be fixed.

Comment: My device section actually lists the correct driver and correct board name. It's counter-intuitive to me to change a spefic to a general device. Please confirm the degree of certainty to your solution.  Also, I noticed that when I open the ubuntu settings display, after a clean install but before installing nvidia-updates-331.38, it said the brand name of the TV followed by 32". Problem is - my TV is 49.9". Not sure if that would be the factor.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me: I am not proposing you to change your specific device configurations for generic ones, I just said that if that section doesn't exist in your xorg.conf you would have to add a generic section in order to follow my instruction, if it is not the case, just skip that part and follow the rest of the instructions, which summarizes in adding the line `Option        "metamodes" "DFP-1: 1280x720 { ViewPortIn=1280x720,ViewPortOut=1230x672-25-24 }"` under your 'Section "Device"'.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I'll check as soon as I get home from work. Evn

Answer (score 0):

There's a three word answer I found by Linus Torvalds that I think sums it up. Tried nvidia-persistenced last night. No avail. Still have to open nvidia-settings on boot. It still displays the accurate adjustments but I still have to toggle underscan, apply, toggle back, apply. I'm with Linus.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issues with the 331.38 drivers on my 8800 GT and I was unable to resolve the issue by modifying the `xorg.conf` file, however I was able to fix it by adding the following to the logon script in `/etc/profile.d`:

```
nvidia-settings --assign 0/CurrentMetaMode="DFP-0: 1920x1080 { ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1834x1031+43+24 }"
```

Rodrigo's Answer above pointed me in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

another way to do it is to add a command via Startup Application GUI

the command to run is:

```
sh -c 'nvidia-settings --assign 0/CurrentMetaMode="VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, LVDS-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +3840+0 {viewportout=1832x1030+44+24}"'
```

I also removed ~/.config/monitors.xml

worked for me - plain and simple

Comment: **Removing `monitors.xml` can lead to a black screen on some systems...** Dangerous advice this is...

Comment: after an update to:  
`tj@TJ-G75VW:~$ uname -a`  
`Linux TJ-G75VW 3.16.0-44-generic #59~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 7 15:07:27 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`  

I had to select 331.113 binary driver (proprietary and tested) from:  
`tj@TJ-G75VW:~$ sudo software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4`

Comment: Also added:  
`nvidia-settings --assign 0/CurrentMetaMode="VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, LVDS-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +3840+0 {viewportout=1832x1030+44+24}"`  

to the bottom of the ~/.profile  so when display locks  it shall not get messy again (without this line after I logged back in from locked screen I had my screens overlapped on one another)

Comment: @Fabby  thnx I shall not delete monitors.xml anymore and nor will I propose that to anyone anymore. Follow up Qestion: isn't monitors.xml regenerated by nvidia-settings?

Comment: Nope...  `nvidia-settings` is for X, not specific to Unity.  and if you tell OPs to rename or to edit `monitors.xml`, that's fine!  I've solved quite a few problems here by editing it...  (but haven't dug into how to regenerate, I suspect system settings, but don't know)

Answer (score 0):

nVidia proprietary driver 352.63 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. GeForce GT610 GPU Still seems to have the same over/underscan issue. Change the over/underscan setting in the nVidia interface only adjusts the menu bar, etc to fit the screen. Desktop goes off-screen & windows go off-screen (similar to pan/scan mode for videos).

Found a solution here: https://askubuntu.com/a/491498/486441

This worked for me. I did notice further down in xorg.conf in

Section "Screen"
a similar "metamodes" line to the fix. For mine it showed

Option     "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {viewportout=1220x686+30+16}
So was thinking maybe the "+30+16" should be negative maybe? Anyway the previously mentioned fix worked for me so I'm not gonna mess with it :D

Only posted it again seeing as I've only just signed up here (so can't even upvote :/ ), & that this is still an issue.

Another thing I did notice was the over/underscan issue also misaligned the mouse cursor (the number of times I clicked on the wrong box, or selected the wrong window >:| ), and also seemed to create a ghosting effect on the desktop.