# How to fix the physical size of a display in xrandr?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution, xrandr

In a nutshell, my problem is that my TV is overscanning and I have nothing like a "Screen Fit" option in the TV.

The TV is a Samsung model LN32R71B that I believe is providing a corrupted EDID file, as my /var/log/Xorg.0.log file contains an "Indeterminate output size" line related to this EDID file. Also, `xrandr` says that the output HDMI1 (this TV) has size 160mm x 90mm, but I think it should be 710mm x 400mm, because it is 32'' and 16:9 (see [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_size)). Moreover, the resolutions that `xrandr` shows for HDMI1 are completely different from the ones supported by the TV (as seen on its manual). I tried to manually use different officially supported resolutions without success, for instance, by doing:

```
cvt -v 1360 768 60.015
xrandr --newmode "1360x768_60.01"   84.75  1360 1432 1568 1776  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 1360x768_60.01
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1360x768_60.01
```

Also, I tried using `gtf` instead of `cvt`, but it did not work. More importantly, I tried to fix the physical size of HDMI1 by means of

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --fbmm 710x400
```

, but it does not work, as executing `xrandr` keeps telling me that HDMI1 is still 160mm x 90mm. Can you help me?

P.S.: I am not completely sure that the EDID file is corrupt, because this TV works fine on a computer with Windows...

## Edit 0:

My system is an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit, and on the GPU info,

```
sudo lshw -C display
```

returns

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:68 memory:c1000000-c1ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:70 memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c01fffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c2000000-c203ffff memory:c2040000-c205ffff
```

Comment: you could manually specify the screen size in the xorg.conf file, in the `Section "Monitor"`, could you? The xorg.conf man page suggests you could use `DisplaySize`: ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R6.8.2/doc/xorg.conf.5.html

Comment: To check if TV/monitor is supplying EDID information (good or bad) install the package "read-edid".  Then run get-edid to see if any/which i2c buses numeric identifiers can be scanned to get EDID information -- most probably bus 0.  Then (assuming bus 0) do  get-edid -b 0 > /tmp/edid.dat followed by parse-edid < /tmp/edid.dat.  If the data is good, then the first line will be "Checksum Correct", followed by monitor information including display size plus valid modelines which can be used for desired resolution(s) in xorg.conf (prefereably new split-format  xorg.conf.d/32-monitor.conf).

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't help much but here's an xorg.conf fix for nVidia proprietary drivers. Not sure if this would be related to xrandr, & you don't mention what GPU your using to connect to the TV.

https://askubuntu.com/a/491498/486441

Just came across this one also
[Ubuntu 15.04 & ultrawide monitor. How to set max resolution? EDIT:Solved!](https://askubuntu.com/q/663552/486441)
using xrandr but had to create a xorg.conf

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I don't think it will work, as I have two GPUs, one from Intel and one from AMD, but none from Nvidia. Also, I don't know how `xrandr` and xorg.conf interact nowadays. I edited my question and put this information in **Edit 0**.

Answer (score 0):

For the records, even though this might be semi-helpful: i had a similar problem and found here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=171374 that this can be related to using an adapter. In my case i was using DP-to-HDMI adapter, and that was indeed responsible for wrong screen dimensions detected. I could solve it by not-using the adapter for that screen, but i guess not everyone has that option :/